# How to inject Elements into an into unrelated component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm sitting at a project with a context menu, which gets it's content (`JSX.Elements`) passed via a `State` (the `setState` gets passed from the `App` entry component all the way up). So any component rendered can decide how its context menu sidebar should look like.
I know that's not a good pattern, mostly because `Elements` don't belong into a state (they can't be compared properly), and maybe also because passing `setState` is a bit verbose.

What I'm not sure is what's the appropriate way to approach this.

- Passing a state with a string denoting which `Elements` shall be rendered? I'ld remove the inversion of control (i.e. the sidebar doesn't need to know its contents) then because there'ld be a place where all strings are mapped to `Elements`, and I'ld rather keep that pattern as it is.
- Working with a `Context`? Or is that as bad as working with a state, apart from the benefit that I wouldn't have to pass the `setState` method anymore? Anyway, I don't see a way to update that `Context` from another component without passing a `setState` to it, again, and set the `Elements` as data there, again.
- Passing an anchor element (from the context sidebar) so all components could update it by themselves? Being new to react, I'm not really sure how that's viable (but I guess it is), but imo that would make even harder to understand what's actually happening later on. And I'ld be a bit afraid of infinite rendering loops.
- Anything completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are making a structural mistake known as prop drilling.
the suggested ways to handle these kinds of use cases is to utilize either Redux or Context API provided by Reactjs.
[Here](https://dev.to/ruppysuppy/redux-vs-context-api-when-to-use-them-4k3p) is a reasonable article about differences and use cases.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know that prop drilling isn't really nice, that's why I was proposing `Context` as my second idea. But what I'm more hesitant about is whether passing `JSX.Components` (or generally spoken, complex objects or even functions) in the `Context` is more appropriate here than in states.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you could provide more info about your use case i guess i can be more of a help. But, passing JSX as components or saving is state in not something that i would recommend due to the fact that i certain there are more robust solutions for your use case

Comment: Well, it's hard to provide more info because I don't want to make the question too specific to my sole case, and I also don't want really know which infos are lacking. I did some more research on `Contexts` though and it seem that they at least don't cause a re-render on all components but only on the consumers. So even if the `JSX.Elements` I'm passing here can't be checked for equality to avoid unnecessary re-renders (same problem as with `useState`), the re-renders would at least be limited to certain components (and their children). And ofc, as a bonus the prop drilling would disappear.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point i wanted to tell. Although, i still believe passing JSX components like this is not necessary in general case. However, Context will solve your prop drilling and continuous re-rendering issue.

Comment: Alright then, I'll go with `Context` instead. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Well, I reallized that I can't update this `Context` from another component without resorting to `setState` again, and the state would be again a set of `JSX.Elements` - which is something inappropriate for a `state` b/c it can't be checked for equality. But yeah, I guess there is not "proper" way to settle this in react.